# Results of radare2 are not correct

Tags: ida, disassembly, radare2

I am using radare2 to analyze libpng_amd64.so.1.6.34, commands are as follows:

```
r2 = r2pipe.open(binary_file)
r2.cmd('aaa')
funcs = r2.cmdj('aflj')
```

len(funcs) is 461, but the number of functions got by IDA is 526, besides the numbers of strings, imports, exports... are also different. 
I checked the result of radare2 and found some issuses, for example, the function `png_write_row` is followed by `png_write_rows`. Radare2 can not identity the second function `png_write_rows` and consider all code of those two functions to `png_write_row`. IDA works correctly.

Why they are different? and Why radare2 can not identity functions correctly? how can I use it to get correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to different algorithms used for analysis or different options set for those. `r2` (as well as `IDA` and `Ghidra`) has multiple options that can influence how the code is analyzed and how the functions (and other elements) are being recognized.

In this case, `png_write_rows`, as far as I can see, this function is not called anywhere in the lib and also doesn't have standard function prologue so it might be for the reason that `r2` doesn't recognize it and mark correctly as a function.

How to fix? You can always modify the final analysis and define a function where the flag for `png_write_rows` is. You can do that in Visual mode by typing 'df' (define function).

Anyway, I would open an [r2 issue](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues) to get some more info if this is a case of correct `analysis flags` (check `e~anal`) or why for some other reason `r2` doesn't recognize correctly some elements in this lib.